# default data type of primary keys in models (django), The current path, url '/app' didn't match any of these

Tags: django, model

As far as I know, the default data type of id is integer for models in Django.

For example, if I have such a model inside my models.py file, Django sets a id(primary key) for every instance of it and Django increments it automatically like 1,2,3 etc.  :

```
class AuctionListing(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
url = models.URLField()


def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}"
```

Since it sets id(primary key) automatically as a data type of integer, I can create such a url in the url.py file :

```
    path("<int:listing_id>", views.listing, name="listing")
```

And my views.py file:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {"auctionList":AuctionListing.objects.all()} )
```

also, index.html file :

```
{% for listing in auctionList %}
    <a href="url 'listing' listing.id"><img src = "{{listing.url}}" alt = "{{listing.name}}"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

The issue with this, when it passes listing.id to  the path("int:listing_id", views.listing, name = "listing"),  it doesn't pass id as integer but as str. That's why, path doesn't accept it since it is int:listing_id and  when I go to the page, it gives me this error : "

The current path, url 'listing' listing.id, didn't match any of these".

When I change int:listing_id to str:listing_id it works. I wonder if the default  data type of id is a string data type in Django? As far as I know it should be a data type of integer. Can someone explain please?

By the way, I am inheriting from AbstractUser.
DB is sqlite3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the default object primary key data type in django is int but if you want to access it you should either declare your own primary key field or use the default name which is `pk`, in that case your urls should look something like this:

```
path("", views.listings, name="listings"),
path("<int:pk>", views.listing, name="listing")
```

and your views something like this:

```
def index(request):
    listings = AuctionListing.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'listings.html', {'listings': listings'}

def listing(request, pk):
    listing = AuctionListing.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'listing.html', {'listing': listing'}
```

and in your `listings.html`:

```
{% for listing in listings %}
    <a href="{% url 'listing' listing.pk %}">{{ listing.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am stupid as hell. How could I forget it ? Probably, lack of oxygen in my veins killed my neurons.

Comment: @AliUyanık don't beat yourself up, we all started somewhere :)